# Overriding class attribute in Django ChoiceField / select

Tags: django, django-forms

I'd like to add `class="form-control"` (Bootstrap 3) to my custom Django form.

My fields need to be rendered as follows in my template (just to show I'm not using `{{form}}`:

```
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    {{ field }}
{% endfor %}
```

I realize the `Meta` class should be used to override the `widgets`, e.g. as following for a `TextField`:

```
class Meta:
    ...
    widgets = {
        'info': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
    }
```

This works, but one of my form elements is a `<select>` field.

I tried the below, but no luck. With the below:

```
widgets = {
     'tags': forms.ChoiceField(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
}
```

I get:

> `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'attrs'`

Comment: Have you checked [django-bootstrap3](https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap3) which allows rendering Django forms with Boostrap classes?

Comment: ChoiceField is a field, not a widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `forms.Select()`:

```
widgets = {
    'tags': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}), 
    'info': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
}
```